# Overriding user uploaded photo in outlook by photo uploaded in AD

Tags: user-profile-property, profile-sync

We have an Active Directory where all the photos of the users are already uploaded. Now, in SharePoint Online, the users are uploading their photos in their respective Delve site.

Because of this, the Delve pictures are getting Synced with SP User Profiles and is being displayed everywhere in SharePoint Online.

So, my question is, if there is a possible way to display the photos present in the AD and not from anywhere else.

Also, if you can let me know that:

- If the profile photos of every user syncs form Active Directory present in SharePoint On-premises to SharePoint Online by default? Or is it compulsory for us to run a
  PowerShell script to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AAD Connect will synchronize the `thumbnailPhoto` attribute from Active Directory. This picture will make it's way into Exchange Online and SharePoint Online.

Keep in mind the resolution you'll get from this attribute is very poor. It will not look good in many locations in Office 365.

Users can still upload their own picture, as well.